# nuspec file doesn't add nuget the right way in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Here is the nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>CrossDomain.Logging</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <authors>Daniel Gustafsson</authors>
    <owners>AAES E-Solution</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Add package to remove direct dependency to CrossDomain.Logging</description>
    <tags>CrossDomain Logging</tags>    
 </metadata>    
 <files>
    <file src="CrossDomain.Application.Services.Logging.dll" target="lib\Logging.dll"></file>
 </files>
</package>
```

Everything seems to work. When i install the package it gets installed and it adds a package to the local package folder. It also adds a reference to the project but it gets the annoying warning sign on the side in solution explorer.

However if i delete the reference and adds it manually it works. 
Am i missing something in the spec file?

[image]

---- EDIT -----

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <solution>
   <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="false" />
 </solution>
 <config>
  <!--
  Used to specify the default location to expand packages.
   See: NuGet.exe help install
  See: NuGet.exe help update
  -->
     <add key="repositorypath" value="..\..\..\External\main\Packages" />
</config>
 <packageRestore>
   <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
  <add key="enabled" value="True" />

   <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
  <add key="automatic" value="True" />
 </packageRestore>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Go back to nuget.org and check the samples they provided. `target="lib\Logging.dll"` is the worst case you can write. Usually package owners give more specific monikers.

Comment: The thing is that we have added a nuget.config that creates the packages in a specific folder. If i add more path to the target it will just repeat itself and become CrossDomain.Logging 1.0/lib/CrossDomain.Logging 1.0/lib/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by placing the dll in below format,

```
<file src="bin\Release\<name>.dll" target="lib\net20"/>
```

Where target the target framework like net35, net40, net45.

Also, when adding the reference, please verify your packages.config as well,

```
<package id="<package>" version="<version>" targetFramework="net20" />
```

Also, open csproj in notepad and verify the `<HintPath>` for the referenced library and that the file is present.

Also check that the processor architecture (32 bit & 64 bit), version are correct.

If it's showing the warning sign again, please build the project and provide build output as well. That will provide the details about where it's looking for the dll